# How to bind Marionette.ItemView to existing page element, instead of passing in a template?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

Our application uses Mustache templates in the index.mustache and makes the initial API call with Symfony instead of using Backbone. This is so the user won't be staring at a blank screen on initial page load.

Now how can we use Marionette afterwards to bind to the rendered page elements in the DOM (so we can manipulate the data and add interactivity), instead of passing a new template?

As far as our research suggests, we need to always pass in a template to Marionette Layout and ItemView, or we get a 'no template error'.

Is there an [**el**](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) property we can use, just like in Backbone?
The other option would be to extend Marionette.View, but it is not advised to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just should instantiate the view, without rendering.
http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/PkNTp/

```
var ItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    el : '.content',
    events : {
        'click' : 'clickHandler'
    },
    clickHandler : function () {
        this.$el.append('clickHandler');
    }
});

new ItemView();
```

Comment: I have no idea what I was doing wrong. Now it works... Weird. Thanks Vitaliy!

Comment: I would suggest one small change: don't hardcode the `el` in to the view itself. This will cause headaches later. Instead, pass the `el` in to the constructor options: `new ItemView({el: ".content"});`

Comment: @DerickBailey Thanks for the advice, yes this is certainly more reusable. Big fan of Marionette Btw! :)

Comment: If you don't render, will you still have access to the 'ui' object?

Comment: @earl3s, as i've made some investigation, this is not initialized :(

Comment: @earl3s, you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312075/availability-of-ui-elements-in-marionette-view for more info